# How to check if a string is null or empty in a SPARQL query?

Tags: rdf, sparql

How do I check and filter out empty strings using sparql.

Comment: In the title, you ask about null or empty, but in the question you only mention empty strings.  Are you asking about values that are `""`, or values that aren't bound?  Also, what does this have to do with [tag:swrl]?  It doesn't appear to have anything to do with [tag:swrl], so I'm removing the tag, at least for now.

Comment: You are rigth about [SWRL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swrl), thanks for the editing. And I mention about null or empty. Because I can always make my property empty ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear what you mean.  There are are a few problems that you could be having, and your question doesn't make it clear which you've got.  Checking whether, e.g., a person has a `foaf:name` that's `""` is a simple pattern `select * where { ?x foaf:name "" }`, but checking whether someone has *no* foaf:name requires `select * where { ?x <>* ?x filter not exists { ?x foaf:name [] } }`. if you've already got results and they include some bindings with undefined values, then you'd need something like `filter bound(?name)` or `filter !bound(?name)`, depending on whether you want

Comment: to keep or exclude them.  To make this question better, show us an example the query that you've got, the results that you're *actually* getting and the results that you'd *like* to be getting (which might be more or less than what you're actually getting, depending on what you're trying to achieve).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
BIND(BOUND(?abc) && strlen(?abc)>0 as ?check)
```

Answer (score 2):

to check a resource (?resource) with a property (?property) with an empty string is:

```
SELECT ?resource WHERE{  ?resource ?property "" }
```

I developed this answer using the information [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806001051/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/1518/null-string-in-sparql) and a good place to look to solution of semantics web is [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string is empty or NULL, you can create a new variable

```
SELECT ?s ?o ?len_o  
WHERE {?s prefix:predicate ?o  
        BIND(STRLEN(?o) AS len_o)  
      }
```

Then you can filter on the variable value

```
SELECT ?s ?o ?len_o  
WHERE {?s prefix:predicate ?o  
        BIND(STRLEN(?o) AS ?len_o)  
        FILTER (?len_o = 0)  
      }
```

Or you can directly create a filter

```
SELECT ?s ?o  
WHERE {?s prefix:predicate ?o  
        FILTER (STRLEN(?o) != 0)  
      }
```